# Como mostrar o número registros em PDO usando COUNT( * )?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olá estou fazendo um sisteminha que faz listagem no banco de dados as ultimas atualizações , até já tá tudo certo , só que queria imprimir na tabela o número de total atualizações que o usuário fez . Como posso fazer isso ? Obrigado desde já .

Tipo mais ou menos usando o SELECT COUNT( * )

Esse é o código que faz o Foreach

```
<?php
        $data           = $_POST["data"];
        $codusuario     = $_POST["codusuario"];
         $cRelatorios = new cRelatorios();
          $relatorio = $cRelatorios->RetornaAtualizacoesFuncionarios($data,$codusuario);
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($relatorio);


            if(!empty($relatorio)){

                     Foreach($relatorio as  $value){
                      // echo "<pre>"; print_r($value); exit;
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td><center>". $value["usuario"] ."</center></td>";
                        echo "<td><center>". $value["data"] ."</center></td>";
                        echo "<td><center>". $value["codigo"] ."</center></td>";
                        echo "<td>". $value["nome"] ."</td>";
                        echo "<td>". $value[""] ."</td>";
                        echo count($relatorio);//Quero que imprima só uma vez dentro do <td>
                        echo "</tr>";

                                   }
    }

              ?>
```

E essa é parte de minha Query PDO

```
public function RetornaAtualizacoesFuncionarios($data,$codusuario){ 
        $WHERE = array() ;
       if( !empty( $codusuario    ) ) {$WHERE[] = "codusuario = $codusuario";};
       if( !empty( $data   ) ) {$WHERE[] = "DATE_FORMAT(data,'%Y-%m') = '$data'";};
       $WHERE[] = "tipregistro = 'mysql'ORDER BY funcionarios.data DESC";
    try {

         $Query = "SELECT
                       COUNT(usuario) as qtd, 
                        DISTINCT(funcionarios.usuario),
                        date_format(funcionarios.data,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as data ,
                        codigo,
                        nome 
                            FROM funcionarios
                                      "; 

        if( !empty($WHERE) )$Query .= ' WHERE '.implode(' AND  ', $WHERE );

        // echo "<pre>"; print_r($Query);
         include_once $_SESSION['pmodel'].'/mysqlconnection_class.php';
               $p_sql = MysqlConnection::getInstance()->prepare($Query);

                $_retorno = array(); 
                if($p_sql->execute()) {
                    while ($_result = $p_sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
                        $_retorno[] = $_result; 
                    }
                }
                return $_retorno;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: agrupe suas as atualizacoes de cada usuario e depois veja a quantidade que há

Comment: @Gumball mas como faço para publicar o resultado junto com as tags do foreach ?

Comment: @Fbor Teria como por uma respostar como eu poderia fazer isso ?

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que fazer um `count()` na sua consulta e recuperar no PHP.

```
$Query = "SELECT 
COUNT(codigo) AS qtd,
funcionarios.usuario,
date_format(funcionarios.data,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as data ,
codigo,
nome 
FROM funcionarios";

if( !empty($WHERE) )$Query .= ' WHERE '.implode(' AND  ', $WHERE );

$Query .= " GROUP BY funcionarios.usuario";
```

### PHP

Dentro do `foreach()` que tem que ser letra minúscula.

```
$value['qtd']
```

Comment: Pois é quando faço dessa forma dar esse erro SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT(funcionarios.usuario), date_format(funcionarios.data,'%d/%m' at line 2

Comment: Posta sua nova query na pergunta pra vermos

Comment: já postei a nova query

Comment: Beleza. Postei uma nova maneira de fazer. Testa.

Comment: dar o mesmo erro amigo

Comment: Dá um echo $Query e posta aqui o resultado. E tenta dar um espaço depois de FROM funcionarios

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT ultima_atualizacao , count(ultimaatualizacao) as total
  FROM suatable
 GROUP BY ultima_atualizacao
```

é só um exemplo aprimore para seu contexto e tente desta forma acredito que seja mais fácil

Comment: ele dar o mesmo erro que a query de cima .Tentei ajeitar de várias formas e nada dar o mesmo erro.

Comment: executou somente o codigo sql em algum ambeinte de testes ??

Comment: hurum mas ele sempre dar erro SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT(funcionarios.usuario), date_format(funcionarios.data,'%d/%m' at line 2